# How to add reminder to webform?

Tags: 7, webforms

I had added date field to webform. Is there a way to detect this date field to compare current date. If correct, it will send email.

I had download date reminder module, however it seem does not link with webform. Any solution?

Please note: This is totally not related to webform submission date.

Comment: I seem to understand that you want to consider the **webform submissions** which have a value of your date field's equal to today's date, right? Also: (1) what should be the actual "trigger" of such eMails? and (2) can you create a view of the webform submissions with such date equal to today?

Comment: @pierre, Exampe: Form A date = 24th of Apr 2017 which is today. Form B date = 25th of Apr which is tml. Today, only Form A will resend email to user. (because comparison between form A date and today date are the same). Form B will resend email tml.

Comment: what about my (1) and (2)?

Comment: @Pierre, 1) Send email - Content of the email will be related to webform field value. 2) As a mention. Nothing related to webform submission date. Only compare between Date Field and Current Date.